# How to run Linux sort from C using system()

Tags: c, linux

I have an in-memory array created with int arraydata[100] and I want to sort it using the Linux `sort` command.  Ideally I would like a simple one-line solution that looks like `system("ls -lh >/dev/null 2>&1");` where I pipe the array to the appropriate fd and run `sort` on it, but the examples I have seen use named files like file.txt.

The question of how to run Linux `sort` from C was discussed in  [How to call UNIX sort command on data in pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809692/how-to-call-unix-sort-command-on-data-in-pipe), but in that question he was forking a new process, which I do not want to do.

Can I run `sort` with a simple one-line program using `system()`?  If not, what would be the lowest-overhead way to accomplish running `sort` on my array?

Comment: Do you mean [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) or do you mean `sort` as in the sort *command*? If you're doing C you can read directories without having to open external commands.

Comment: No, I want to use the Linux sort command.

Comment: What is linux `sort()`. There is sort command, in which case there are no `()`, it's not a function, a command.

Comment: When you say `sort()` you mean, specifically, a function. Saying `sort` as in command is a whole different thing. In the POSIX world there is a very strong convention in use here to differentiate the two things, as otherwise there's endless confusion as many commands have function counterparts with the same name.

Comment: Really?  Why in the world would you sort in-memory data via the external `sort` command?

Comment: I want to use sort.  Sorry for my misuse of ().  See https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

Comment: You want to sort the array __or__ you want to _output_ a sorted array? The first one is _a lot_ more complex if using `sort` command then the latter.

Comment: To run your data through the `sort` command, you absolutely *will* fork.  If you use `system()` to run the command then the fork will just be inside that.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `sort` command and not the `qsort` routine? This is an important part of the question because, if the answer is, say, that you have a school assignment requiring `sort`, then the assignment is to teach you about features like pipes and commands, and the assignment specifics should be stated, and the answer needs to speak to those issues. On the other hand, if you do not have such a specific assignment, then the answer is it is an absurdly wrong approach to seek to use the `sort` command to sort in-memory data, and you ought to use `qsort` or, preferably, `qsort_r`.

Comment: Is it a mistake because there is too much overhead involved?

Comment: Using `sort` has a massive amount of overhead compared to calling `qsort_r`. It is like the difference between driving to the store for flour instead of using what is in your pantry.

Comment: There is an incredible amount of overhead involved in spawning and reading input and output of an external program compared to simple memory operations required to sort.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil - thanks very much for that.  I will look into using qsort_r.  When I want to sort a large file, then it looks like sort would be appropriate, but not for a small amount of data.

Comment: And aside from *performance* overhead, sending your data out for an external `sort` run is a lot more complicated code-wise.  Maybe not Rube Goldberg territory, but heading in that direction.

Comment: One more question.  Is there a file size threshold over which sort would be better / faster than qsort_r?

Comment: `Is there a file size` what file? You have `int arraydata[100]`, it is in memory, there are no files. There are many sorting algorithms, the answer if _your program_ will be faster than some _other_ program called `sort` just depends on the programs contents. What if `sort` command just calls `qsort_r`? It's a too broad question.

Comment: @RTC222, if you already have the data in memory as an array, then no, the `sort` command is strictly inferior to `qsort()` and `qsort_r()` for sorting it.

Comment: No, I mean if I did have a file to sort, which is much more data.  This question is not entirely academic -- it's just in the current situation I have in-memory data.  But when I do have a large file, which would be better, sort of qsort?

Comment: It's quite possible that `sort` is implemented with `qsort` under the hood. The use of `qsort` is essential learning anyway.

Comment: If you already have the data in a file, and you do not intend to load it into an array in a C program, then `qsort` is not really an option in the first place.

Comment: @RTC222 It's all about using the right tool for the job. If you have an array of numbers to sort, `qsort()` is the right choice for all the reasons given. To use `sort`, you'll essentially be writing those numbers into a file (a pipe is a kind of file) and then starting another process and then reading the sorted numbers from another file. If the numbers are *already* in a file, then `sort` is likely the better choice because it already does all that reading an writing. If you want good advice, you really need to edit the question to provide some clarity around your *actual* goal.

Comment: Your link explains what `sort` does, it willl "sort lines of text files". If you want to sort lines of text files, then it's the perfect tool for the job. If you want to do something else, it's not the right tool for the job. Is your array a text file whose lines you want to sort? If not, then you want a different tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be the lowest-overhead way to accomlish calling sort [command] on my array?

To answer your question, the following program does the "standard" `pipe` + `fork` + `dup2` + `exec` to spawn a `sort` program to communicate with. Then the parent `fdopens` the pipes to `printf`/`scanf` on them. Finally, parent waits for child program termination. The program is nowhere near perfect, for many reasons, including using `assert` for cheap error handling.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sort_them_with_sort_command(size_t arrlen, int arr[arrlen]) {
  int in[2];
  int err = pipe(in);
  assert(err == 0);
  int out[2];
  err = pipe(out);
  assert(err == 0);
  int pid = fork();
  assert(pid >= 0);
  if (pid == 0) {
    close(in[1]);
    dup2(in[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(out[0]);
    dup2(out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    const char *const cmd[2] = {"sort", "-n"};
    execvp(cmd[0], (char *const *)cmd);
    assert(0);
  }
  close(in[0]);
  FILE *inf = fdopen(in[1], "w");
  assert(inf != NULL);
  close(out[1]);
  FILE *outf = fdopen(out[0], "r");
  assert(outf != NULL);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arrlen; ++i) {
    err = fprintf(inf, "%d\n", arr[i]);
    assert(err > 0);
  }
  fclose(inf);
  close(in[1]);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arrlen; ++i) {
    err = fscanf(outf, " %d", &arr[i]);
    assert(err == 1);
  }
  fclose(outf);
  close(out[0]);
  waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
}

int main() {
  int arraydata[10];
  const size_t arraydatalen = sizeof(arraydata) / sizeof(*arraydata);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arraydatalen; i++) {
    arraydata[i] = rand();
  }
  printf("Before sorting:\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arraydatalen; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", arraydata[i]);
  }
  sort_them_with_sort_command(arraydatalen, arraydata);
  printf("After sorting:\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arraydatalen; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", arraydata[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Program outputs:

```
Before sorting:
1804289383
846930886
1681692777
1714636915
1957747793
424238335
719885386
1649760492
596516649
1189641421
After sorting:
424238335
596516649
719885386
846930886
1189641421
1649760492
1681692777
1714636915
1804289383
1957747793
```

> Can I run sort with a simple one-line program using system()?

As `system()` executes another process with no any means of communication, you would have to write a means of communication between processes. You could open a pipe and then write from the shell to one part of the pipe and read in a separate thread in C from the other side of the pipe. Either way, this is way overkill for sorting.

Comment: Note that in general, using two pipes to connect to another process like this requires care, lest it deadlock when the pipe buffers fill up.

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental to [@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956268/2402272), here's the `qsort` alternative to their `sort_them_with_sort_command()` function:

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y) {
    int xval = *(const int *)x;
    int yval = *(const int *)y;

    if (xval == yval) return 0;
    return xval < yval ? -1 : 1;
}

void sort_them_with_qsort(size_t arrlen, int arr[arrlen]) {
    qsort(arr, arrlen, sizeof(arr[0]), compare);
}
```

(`qsort_r()` confers no advantage over `qsort()` in this case.)

So to reiterate one of my comments on the question, why in the world would you use the `sort` command if you're already poised to use `qsort()`?  Look how much simpler the `qsort()` alternative is!